# Show map between tensor products is a $R-$algebra homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, ring-homomorphism

Prove that, if $A,B,C,D$ are algebras over a commutative ring R, and
$f : A \rightarrow B, g : C \rightarrow D$ are homomorphisms of $R-$algebras, then
$f \otimes g : A \otimes C \longrightarrow B \otimes D$ is a homomorphism of $R-$algebras.

I know I have to prove the map is a ring homomorphism and a $R-$module homomorphism. The "scalar" property seems easy. We take $r\in R, x\in A, y\in C$:

$$(f\otimes g)(r(x\otimes y))=(f\otimes g)(rx\otimes y)=f(rx)\otimes g(y)=rf(x)\otimes g(y)=r(f(x)\otimes g(y))$$

Then, for the product, take $x,z\in A, y, w\in C$:
$$(f\otimes g)((x\otimes y)(z \otimes w)) = (f\otimes g)(xz \otimes yw)= \\=f(xz)\otimes g(yw)= f(x)f(z)\otimes g(y)g(w) =\\ =(f(x)\otimes g(y))(f(z)\otimes g(w))=(f\otimes g)(x\otimes y)(f\otimes g)(z \otimes w)$$

My problem is checking that, for $x,z\in A, y, w\in C$ we have:
$$(f\otimes g)((x\otimes y)+(z\otimes w))= (f\otimes g)(x\otimes z)+(f\otimes g)(z\otimes w)$$

I must be missing something here about the addition of decomposable tensors... Can someone help with this?

Comment: How is $f\otimes g$ defined for you?

Comment: @EricWofsey I only have that $(f_1\otimes· · ·\otimes f_n)(x_1\otimes· · ·\otimes x_n) = f_1(x_1)\otimes · · ·\otimes f_n(x_n)$ where each $f_i$ is a homomorphism of $R-$modules and $x_i\in M$, an $R-$module over a commutative ring...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, $f\otimes g$ is defined using the universal property of the tensor product, as the unique $R$-module homomorphism $A\otimes C\to B\otimes D$ such that $(f\otimes g)(x\otimes y)=f(x)\otimes g(y)$ for all $x\in A$ and $y\in C$.  So, by definition it is automatically an $R$-module homomorphism, and so you don't need to do any work to check that part.  To put it another way, $f\otimes g$ is defined by setting $(f\otimes g)(x\otimes y)=f(x)\otimes g(y)$ and then extending to the rest of $A\otimes C$ such that it preserves addition (and the universal property guarantees that this extension is actually well-defined).

Comment: So I only needed to check that last part regarding the image of the product right?

Comment: Depending on your definition of algebra, you may also need to check that it sends $1$ to $1$.